# MCSession send resource cancel

Tags: ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I am using multi peer technology in my app (ios7). The user can send a resource with the following method:

```
_progressSend = [session sendResourceAtURL:imageUrl withName: info toPeer:peerID withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        // Implement this block to know when the sending resource transfer completes and if there is an error.
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Send resource to peer [%@] completed with Error [%@]", peerID.displayName, error);
        }
        else {
            // Create an image transcript for this received image resource

        }
    }];
```

The problem is that sometimes it stops half way, or it is really slow. Is there a way to cancel the transmission without disconnecting:

```
[session disconnect];
```

??

Answer (score -1):

You can use the returned `NSProgress` object to cancel the transfer. It has a `-cancel` method and its `.cancellable` should return `YES`.